How to zoom image in and out using mouse location C# windows forms
I want to zoom in to image, so the point under the mouse cursor will stay under the mouse cursor. I have tried:
private void ZoomForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        float oldZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            zoomFactor *= 1.1f;
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            zoomFactor /= 1.1f;
        }

        // Limit zoom factor to avoid excessive zooming
        zoomFactor = Math.Max(0.1f, Math.Min(zoomFactor, 10.0f));

        // Adjust the image offset based on the mouse position
        Point mousePos = e.Location;
        float scaleChange = zoomFactor / oldZoomFactor;
        imageOffset.X = (int)(mousePos.X - scaleChange * (mousePos.X - imageOffset.X));
        imageOffset.Y = (int)(mousePos.Y - scaleChange * (mousePos.Y - imageOffset.Y));

        this.Invalidate();
    } 


protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            if (this.zoomableImage != null)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                int newWidth = (int)(this.zoomableImage.Width * zoomFactor);
                int newHeight = (int)(this.zoomableImage.Height * zoomFactor);
                int x = (this.Width - newWidth) / 2 + imageOffset.X;
                int y = (this.Height - newHeight) / 2 + imageOffset.Y;
                g.DrawImage(this.zoomableImage, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
            }
        }

The image is shifting in an unexpected manner, and the point that was initially under the mouse cursor seems to move around unpredictably. I believe the issue might be due to errors in the mathematical calculations used to adjust the image offset. Although the mouse location is correctly obtained from the wheel action, the calculations to keep the point under the cursor fixed might be incorrect?

Zoom and translate an Image from the mouse location

Just in case I am posting my solution now.
 private void ZoomForm_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       
            if (zoomableImage == null) return;

            // Record old zoom factor
            float oldZoomFactor = zoomFactor;

            // Update zoom factor
            zoomFactor *= e.Delta > 0 ? 1.1f : 1 / 1.1f;
            zoomFactor = Math.Max(0.1f, Math.Min(zoomFactor, 10.0f));

            // Calculate new image dimensions
            int oldWidth = (int)(zoomableImage.Width * oldZoomFactor);
            int oldHeight = (int)(zoomableImage.Height * oldZoomFactor);
            int newWidth = (int)(zoomableImage.Width * zoomFactor);
            int newHeight = (int)(zoomableImage.Height * zoomFactor);

            // Calculate the change in width and height
            float deltaWidth = newWidth - oldWidth;
            float deltaHeight = newHeight - oldHeight;

            // Adjust the image offset based on the mouse position
            Point mousePosition = e.Location;

            // Calculate mouse position relative to the image's center
            float mouseXRel = mousePosition.X - (this.Width / 2f + imageOffset.X);
            float mouseYRel = mousePosition.Y - (this.Height / 2f + imageOffset.Y);

            // Adjust the image offset to keep the mouse position constant relative to the image
            imageOffset.X -= (int)(mouseXRel * deltaWidth / oldWidth);
            imageOffset.Y -= (int)(mouseYRel * deltaHeight / oldHeight);

            // Redraw the form
            this.Invalidate();
        
    }

